# How to bind wget to download through a specific port?

Tags: wget, proxy, bind, port, socks5-proxy

I'm trying to download a file through wget. But I want to download it through a port which I configured as a proxy.
How can I configure wget to download through a specific port in my computer? 
In other words, I want to bind wget to for example "localhost:8080"

Comment: What kind of proxy your special port is configured as? A HTTP proxy, some other protocol proxy, or a generic TCP connection proxy (like SSH port forwarding)?

Comment: I think I'm using socks5 proxy (I'm using Dynamic Forwarding in ssh command)

Comment: 'bind' in sockets is an operation entirely different from and unrelated to using a proxy which is what you want, and the _tag_ 'bind' is for a particular DNS-server _program_ that is not related to either of those. `ssh -D` handles both socks4 and socks5, but 5 is (unsurprisingly) preferred.

Answer (score 2):

`wget` supports http, https and ftp proxies. You can use these types of proxies by typing extra arguments,

```
wget <url> -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080    
wget <url> -e use_proxy=yes -e https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080    
wget <url> -e use_proxy=yes -e ftp_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080
```

or, you can export them as environment variables.

However, in case of a socks5 proxy, I recommend installing `proxychains`. It also supports http, https etc. After installation, you should configure it through `/etc/proxychains.conf`. Then you can use `wget` as,

`proxychains4 wget <url>`

Comment: In it's documentation page it writes that proxychains is just for tcp connections: "This program forces any tcp connection made by any given tcp client to follow through proxy (or proxy chain). It is a kind of proxifier." So what about other protocols?